# Can attributes be applied to templates?

Tags: templates, c++11

Does the C++ standard allow setting attributes on template declarations? For example:

```
[[attr1]] template <typename T [[attr2]] > [[attr3]]
class [[attr4]] C {};
```

I believe `attr4` would be considered a valid attribute for the template instances (i.e., it would be an attribute on `T<int>` and `T<char>`, for example).

However would either `attr1` or `attr3` be considered valid by the compiler (even if it would be ignored)?

Would `attr2` also be valid? I think not, but I'm not sure. The issue would be if it "adds" an attribute to a given type used in instantiation, but IIRC currently template parameters have all attributes ignored.

My interest in `attr1` and/or `attr3` is for a custom test DSL, where a given attribute on a template would automatically force instantiation of the class with a given set of types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I digged into C++ grammar and here are relevant parts:

```
declaration:
    block-declaration
    template-declaration

template-declaration:
    template < template-parameter-list > declaration
```

That forbids `[[attr1]]` and `[[attr3]]`, if you believe me, that `declaration` may not begin with `attribute-specifier-seq`.

---

```
template-parameter-list:
    template-parameter

template-parameter:
    type-parameter

type-parameter:
    type-parameter-key ..._opt identifier_opt

type-parameter-key:
    class
    typename
```

That forbids `[[attr2]]`, `identifier` in regex is `[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*`, with `universal-character-name` and *other implementation-defined characters*.

---

```
declaration:
    block-declaration

simple-declaration:
    decl-specifier-seq_opt init-declarator-list_opt ;

decl-specifier-seq:
    decl-specifier attribute-specifier-seq_opt

decl-specifier:
    type-specifier

type-specifier:
    class-specifier

class-specifier:
    class-head { member-specification_opt }

class-head:
    class-key attribute-specifier-seq_opt class-head-name class-virt-specifier_opt base-clause_opt
```

That allows `[[attr4]]`